# SQL Server Query Help 4

Tags: sql

I’m new to SQL query, I need help on below logic. 
I need to match all the records with current system date and **display 1 if it is match and zero if it is not match with current system date based on the Client_Code**.

Table:

```
Client_Code | HolidayDate | Year
------------+-------------+------
 Testing    |  2/15/2017  | 2017
 Testing    |  3/12/2017  | 2017
 Testing    |  5/23/2017  | 2017
 Testing    |  6/12/2017  | 2017
 Testing    |  7/9/2017   | 2017
 Unilever   |  1/12/2017  | 2017
 Unilever   |  2/17/2017  | 2017
 Unilever   |  3/23/2017  | 2017
 Unilever   |  2/21/2017  | NULL
```

I need output like

```
Client_Code |   Status
------------+----------
  Testing   |    0 
  Unilever  |    1
```

Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: What exactly mean system date?

Answer (score 0):

You should search for all Client_Code if there is a HollidayDate that matches with GETDATE();

Note I've used GETDATE() as "system date".

```
SELECT    c.Client_Code, 
          CASE WHEN COALESCE(t.HolidayDate,0) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS Status
FROM      (SELECT   Client_Code
           FROM     YourTable
           GROUP BY Client_Code) c
LEFT JOIN  YourTable t
ON         t.Client_Code = c.Client_Code
AND        t.HolidayDate = GETDATE();
```

**Update**

GETDATE() returns a datetime value: 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss.ttt'

To check if date part of DATETIME1 = date part of DATETIME2 use:

```
AND DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, t.HolidayDate))  = DATEADD(DAY, 0, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, GETDATE()))
```

OR convert both to varchar using same format:

```
AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), t.HolidayDate, 112) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 112)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.. I modify your query like as below..

 SELECT    c.Client_Code, 
     CASE WHEN t.HolidayDate  = cast(GETDATE() as date) then 1 else 0 end 'Status'
 FROM      (SELECT   Client_Code
      FROM     table
      GROUP BY Client_Code) c
 left JOIN  table t
 ON t.Client_Code = c.Client_Code
 AND t.HolidayDate = GETDATE();
output:
Client_Code Status
Testing 0
uniliver 0

I need output like below

Client_Code Status
Testing 0
uniliver 1

I have records for today's date.
Table: